# Position of texts after rotate

Tags: html, css

When I rotate some span, the texts in there does not align horizontally. 
You can see example below. 
In this example we have three spans that rotate but we have problem with alignment.

```css
body{
    padding-left:10px;
}
.bordered{
  border-left: 2px solid gray;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 4em;
  padding-bottom: 4em;
  padding-left: 1em;
}
 .bordered>span{
    display: block;
    background-color: #ccc;
    padding: 0.34em;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    color: gray;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    margin: 0;
    left: -2em;
    top: ms(3);
  }
```

```html
<section class="hexa-container">
    <section class="hexa-content bordered">
        <span>Services</span>
    </section>
</section>

<section class="hexa-container">
    <section class="hexa-content bordered">
        <span>Works</span>
    </section>
</section>

<section class="hexa-container">
    <section class="hexa-content bordered">
        <span>Blog</span>
    </section>
</section>
```

Comment: how do you want span to look like.?

Comment: I want the spans exactly following each other. You can see the "Works" span is not exactly the same position with "Services" and also "Blog" span.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `transform-origin` property to set the rotation point, be default it's center, and your span texts are of different lengths, that's why alignment gets disturbed on rotation. If you rotate it from left bottom corner it should work.

Below is the modifed CSS and [here](http://jsfiddle.net/LUKGt/370/) is the link for demo

```
body{
    padding-left:10px;
}
.bordered{
  border-left: 2px solid gray;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 4em;
  padding-bottom: 4em;
  padding-left: 1em;
}
 .bordered>span{
     -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
     -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    display: block;
    background-color: #ccc;
    padding: 0.34em;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    color: gray;
    position: absolute;      
    left: -1px;
    top: ms(3);
    margin-left:10px
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this : Set the width for span block. And set the left:[value] accordingly.

HTML

```
<section class="hexa-container">
<section class="hexa-content bordered">
    <span>Services</span>
</section>
</section>
<section class="hexa-container">
<section class="hexa-content bordered">
  <span>Works</span>
</section>
</section>
<section class="hexa-container">
<section class="hexa-content bordered">
  <span>Blog</span>
</section>
</section>
```

Updated CSS

```
body {
padding-left:10px;
}
.bordered {
border-left: 2px solid gray;
position: relative;
padding-top: 4em;
padding-bottom: 4em;
padding-left: 1em;
}
.bordered>span {
display: block;
background-color: #ccc;
padding: 0.34em;
font-weight: 300;
font-size: 0.8em;
color: gray;
position: absolute;
width:80px;
transform:rotate(90deg);
margin: 0;
position:absolute;
left: -3.4em;
}
```

Here is the working **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uns03yrg/)**. Hope this work for you.